# How to align \maketitle

Tags: titles, alignment

I have a background image on the title page of the (book) document, which overlaps with the default settings of `\maketitle`'s Alignment. Thus I want the title to be shifted and lowered, much as shown below

[image]

Comment: Can you add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)? It will be easier to help and answer your question.

Comment: @Celdor I am not really sure what MWE I should even write. The problem is to write the title towards the side of the page as shown in the image.

Comment: The MWE which would show what's your current outcome is and would help to "tailor" the answer to be more specific. Instead, having no information about document class, layout, etc. I could only post a generic answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest solution based on `minipage`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\title{The Title}
\author{John Smith}


\begin{document} 
\noindent%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=2cm]{example-image}%

\nointerlineskip\vspace{\dimexpr-\lineskip+1em}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=\dimexpr\textheight-2cm-1em,valign=t]{example-image}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}
  \centering
  \vspace{3cm}
  \maketitle
  \par 
\end{minipage}

\clearpage
\section{Introduction}
Xxxx
\end{document}
```

EDIT. Remove `1em` in `\vspace` as well as in the second `\includegraphics` which correspond to a small gap and the images will stick together

```latex
% ...
\nointerlineskip\vspace{\dimexpr-\lineskip}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=\dimexpr\textheight-2cm,valign=t]{example-image}%
% ...
```

[image]